# SelectedIndexChange Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, listview, selectedindexchanged

I'm having issue with a dropdownlist updating a textbox, both held within a listview, within an update panel which in turn is in an item template.

**Updated**

I have got this working with the same code without the above containers in a different web page on the same project, however having trouble linking it with the lisview and other containers.

I am unsure of where the problem lies, the onClick isn't firing unless there's a call back to the server, regardless whether the drop down is contained within the containers mentioned above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Using asp (1st) and VB code behind (2nd).

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:panel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" IAllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="true">
<tr>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Details")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" />
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DLL" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DLL_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true "EnableViewState="true">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Maybe</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">I dont know</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Can you repeat</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">the question</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
</asp:panel>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Code behind

```
    Protected Sub DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList) 
    Dim listviewItemThing = DirectCast(sender.parent.NamingContainer, ListViewItem) 
    Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(ddl.NamingContainer.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)

    If ddl.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\han\Documents\Templates\1.txt")
    ElseIf ddl.SelectedValue = 2 Then
        tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\han\Documents\Templates\2.txt")
    ElseIf ddl.SelectedValue = 3 Then
        tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\han\Documents\Templates\3.txt")
    ElseIf ddl.SelectedValue = 4 Then
        tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\han\Documents\Templates\4.txt")
    ElseIf ddl.SelectedValue = 5 Then
        tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\han\Documents\Templates\5.txt")
    ElseIf ddl.SelectedValue = 6 Then
        tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Users\han\Documents\Templates\6.txt")
    Else
        tb.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update 2**

As per request please see attached screen shot of browser console error in debug on VS2013

[image]

And expanded error.
[image]

**Update 3**

Added JQuery to try to force PostBack.

```
         function JsFunction() {
         __doPostBack('DLL_SelectedIndexChanged', '');
     }
```

ASP link to JQ

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" Width="120px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" EnableViewState="true" onchange="javascript:JsFunction()">
```

Comment: what is `ctl` in your `DDL_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: can you also fix markup? why you think that not firing? do you try setup break point to `DDL_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: how you determined that event not firing?

Comment: Break points set on the SelectedIndexChanged, they don't activate when items on the DDL are selected, only when there's a post back to the server.

Comment: do you have any error? possibly in browser console?

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see this before but: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. Not sure what that means.

Comment: can you provide screenshot this error?

Comment: Apparently not as you need 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Thanks - image looks horrible there, try http://i.stack.imgur.com/50SuK.png

Comment: please expand error? for a bit more information

Comment: what if you remove your `onchange="javascript:JsFunction()"`? error still remain? or something change?

Comment: how you use `HtmlEditorExtender`? possibly error with it

Comment: Yes - the error still remains, I was using JQ/JS to try and find away around the main issue of ASP/VB not posting back correctly to fire an event within update panel, listview and itemtemplate.

Comment: methinks your error in other place

Comment: can you try disable, or remove `HtmlEditorExtender` and try without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correct code for your drop down list, so error in other place.

As you see in error message: when you try submit form problem with `HtmlEditorExtender`.
So just remove or disable it for quick fixing problem.

As for error with `HtmlEditorExtender` we need a little bit information, of course, if you still need solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these controls are within the `ItemTemplate` of your `ListView`:

- `FindControl("DDL")` won't work, because it's trying to find the control within the page;
- `ListView1.FindControl("TextBox2")` won't work, because there will be multiple instances of `TextBox2` within the `ListView`.

Try this instead:

```
Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(ddl.NamingContainer.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the source of the issue appears to be with the indexchanged event, it isn't firing unless there's a callback to the server first. I've updated the original question to describe the new findings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't got the typo in your actual code:

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DLL_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Where the event handler is DDL_SelectedIndexChanged.

Have you put a breakpoint on to check whether the event handler is not being called or if it is bailing out at some point after it fails to do the cast you want it to do?

Comment: There's no typos, I've put a much simplified version on here so as not to waste space/time. Yes I've been using breakpoints on the selectedIndexChanged, they fire only when the whole panel is updated, what's even more strange is that this occurs regardless of the DDL is within the update panel. Thanks for your other comment on the other question but I can't see a way around using JQ or JS.