# How to call VB method with JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Hi I've been having issues with ASP and VB DDL not firing the selectedIndexChanged when the drop down value changes - please see my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205527/selectedindexchange-not-firing).

I've been searching for a an asp and vb solution for three days. Coming to the realisation that to force this I'll need to use something client side or change the entirety of my code, which isn't really an option.

Problem is I have very limited experienced with JQuery and JavaScript and cannot get the selectedIndexChanged event to fire from the client side.

How can I do this and is this possible? I've seen a few things on google but either I'm implementing these wrong or they're not working for me in this instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and would answer both my questions.

Thanks in advance.

****Update 1****

Example code I've tried and to give an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

JavaScript

```
         function JsFunction() {
         __doPostBack("DLL", "");
     }
```

DDL snippet

```
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" Width="120px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" EnableViewState="true" onchange="javascript:JsFunction()">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
```

**Update 2**

JS I've also tried without success

```
         function JsFunction() {
         AJAXControlToolKit.HTMLEditor.Announcements.DDL_SelectedIndexChanged();
     }
```

And

```
function JsFunction() {
document.getElementById('<%=DDL.ClientID').click()
}
```

Comment: Looking at your original question, it doesn't look to me like forcing the event to fire from the client side is the right solution, and you'll probably end up with some nasty hack to get round something that shouln't need it.

I've commented on your original question instead.

Comment: I agree, it's not my preferred solution as I don't know anything about JS or JQ but nothing I've tried with ASP or VB is doing the trick.